# SQS fanout with DLQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am looking at using SNS-SQS services to deliver updates to machines running the same service. Since the plan is not for machines to communicate with each other, I was planning on creating a SQS for each machine (SQS would be created at startup).

I am however, not sure how to use a Dead-Letter Queue (DLQ) in such case. Should each SQS have its own DLQ or can I have common one which is shared across my SQS in the region? The concern I have with former approach is too many queues would be created (2x machines) and the concern with later is potential multiple copies of same message in the queue.

What is the best practice and recommended approach when using multiple SQS queues?

Comment: Why use multiple queues? Why not just use one queue and have all machines pull from that queue? SQS provides message visibility features so you don't end up with duplicate processing.

Comment: Multiple queues so as to replicate message to all machines without them having to talk to each other.

Comment: Ah, so you *want* each machine to process all messages. I suggest looking at Kinesis as a better fit for that use case over SQS - model as a single "stream" of data that each worker reads through at their own pace.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be concerned with the number of queues - they don't cost anything - so it really depends on how you plan on using the items in the dead-letter queue. I'll make the assumption that you will have some sort of process to review items in the DLQ to figure out why they were not processed before expiring.

Without knowing the details of what you plan to do, I would think a single DLQ would be better, and if you need to periodically process DLQ records, the processing app/system only needs to monitor that single queue.

Can't see the advantage of multiple DLQs in this case, at least based on your question.

Comment: True. I was leaning towards having a single queue. Your assumption about usage of DLQ is spot on. It ill mainly used for reviewing what did not get processed. However, if the message was not processed by any servers listening in their queue, all  copies of the message would end up in DLQ (i.e. multiple copies of the same message in DLQ). Is that a usual a followed convention?

Answer (score 0):

As you are planning on doing a `fanout process`, having multiple queues is not a harm as long as they are used for asynchronous processing. Else a single queue is preferred. A fanout process in generally used when you want to process a few tasks concurrently by dividing it among several queues and working on them separately. ([to read more about fanout](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/queues-and-notifications-now-best-friends/))

The purpose of a `Dead Letter Queue (DLQ)` is to store messages that cannot be completed successfully by a certain process. Unless your process has a major fault, the number of elements that will be stored in a DLQ should be very less. Therefore it is okay to go ahead and use one DLQ for all other SQSs.

Having multiple DLQs will bring an overhead, where several processes will have to poll the DLQs for failed messages. Having just one DLQ can reduce this overhead.

It is recommended to use multiple DLQs if you want to store different categories of the failed messages.